# A very small Q on sharepoint calculated formulas

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I have a column called "name", I wanna to create a new column to be group. if the file name  contains "MDSN", will return "MDSN" file, if not, will reutrn "non-MDSN"

I found a way `starts-with(@FileLeafRef,"MDKB"),` but I also wanna control the return values, how can I do?

A touph questions for me but can anyone help me out?

Comment: Are you looking for flagging when something STARTS with "MSDN" or CONTAINS? Your question mentions both.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean you're looking to show when a string starts with another string then this will work

```
=IF(LEFT([Name],4)="MSDN","MSDN",non-MSDN")
```

Comment: thank you! but I tried and it didn't work, is that code runing in ASP.NET?

Comment: Its intended to go in as the formula in a CALCULATED COLUMN - which is what I though you wanted from your Q as did Rahil. Put a bit more effort into making good questions and you will be rewarded with good answers.

Answer (score 0):

For Starts with:
=IF(LEFT([Name],4)="MSDN","MSDN",non-MSDN")

For Contains:
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("MSDN",[Name])), "MSDN", "non-MSDN")

For More help on Formula:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx

Comment: ya, but is that in C#, I'm editing the fomula in sharepoint designer "sort and group"

Comment: do you have any other great ideas?

Comment: Nops. Isn't it suitable for your scenario?